# Заполнение Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток! У меня возник такой вопрос. Я хочу добавить боковое меню в андроид  приложение и не знаю как его правильно заполнить.
Меню содержит `ListView`, в котором должны отображаться пункты. Но проблема вот в чем - у каждого пункта должно быть свое название, своя иконка и свой обработчик нажатия. Допустим, заголовки пунктов меню я вытащу из массива хранящегося в `strings.xml`, но этого будет недостаточно, надо еще как-то сопоставить каждому элементу свою иконку и свой обработчик. Но как?
Прописывать это в коде для каждого пункта меню мне кажется не очень рационально/ Подскажите как правильно сделать это?

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего воспользоваться [готовой библиотекой](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer)/

Если хотите самостоятельно реализовать, то делаете массивы, содержащие текст, ссылки на иконки, заполняете этими массивами коллекцию и отправляете ее в адаптер, который будет выводить данные из вашей коллекции в список.
Обработчик у `ListView` уже есть - `onItemClickListener()` и он требуется один, по возвращаемой им позиции вы можете узнать, на какой пункт кликнули.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

        String[] texts = new String[] {
            "Item 1",
            "Item 2",
            "Item 3",
        };

        int[] icons = new int[]{
            R.drawable.icon_1,
            R.drawable.icon_2,
            R.drawable.icon_3,
        };

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            List<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

            for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
                hm.put("text", texts[i]);
                hm.put("icon", Integer.toString(icons[i]) );
                list.add(hm);
            }

            String[] from = { "icon","text" };

            int[] to = { R.id.icon,R.id.text }; // идентификаторы иконки и текста на разметке пункта списка

            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);
            ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        }

 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {

  // действия при клике. position - позиция нажатого элемента
 } 
}
```

[Пример](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/listview-with-images-and-text-using-simple-adapter-in-android/) организации `ListView` с картинками и текстом.